# how to Save ARKIT scanned resources on server?

Tags: arkit, scanning, photogrammetry

I am scanning AR enviornment using ARKit. If i save it on device or app bundle AR apps work perfectly. What i want is to save AR resources on some kind of server and sync that resources while user using app.

Comment: Just convert your ARImages to base64 . Upload them to server through API.                                          Sync resources on AR app , convert base 64 string back to ARImages. Pass these images to ARWorldTracking.